# How to set up SoapUI to log info about failed step(s)?

Tags: logging, log4j, soapui

Default [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j) logging in Soap is done to file `C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\soapui.log`. Everything that is written to `script log` pane (button on the bottom right of the soapUI workspace) could be found there.

Unfortunately there is no information on passed/failed assertions.

Another files in that directory `soapui-errors.log` and `error.log` contain internal errors of [soapui](/questions/tagged/soapui) (as it seems).

I'd like to have the information about passed/failed assertions the same way we see it on the middle of the soapUI workspace:

> Step N [Step name...] OK: took XXXX ms
>   Step N+1 [Step name...] OK: took XXXX ms
>   TestCase failed [Cancelling due to failed test step], time taken = XXXXXX
>   Step N+2 [Step name...] FAILED: took XXXX ms

Is it possible?

Comment: How do you execute the tests? If SOAPUI_HOME/bin/testrunner.bat(.sh) can be used to execute the tests and you would see nice summary at the end of execution. Basically, UI is for designing the test (though tests can be executed) and above utility is for running the tests in headless mode. See if this is helpful.

Comment: @Rao, yes, you are right, when SoapUI is run from command line it writes all error (assertion) information into soapui.log. You should have posted it as an answer.

Comment: Ivan, added the same into answer as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/testrunner.bat(.sh)` can be used to execute the tests and you would see nice summary at the end of execution.

Basically, SoapUI is for designing the tests (though tests can be executed) and above utility is for running the tests in headless mode.